# QScopedPointer Vs boost::scoped_ptr [which one to choose]

Tags: qt, boost, qscopedpointer

If I had an option to choose between `QScopedPointer` and `boost::scoped_ptr`, which one would do most good in the following cases:

```
1. QScopedPointer<QObject> Vs boost::scoped_ptr<QObject>
2. QScopedPointer<QtContainer> Vs boost::scoped_ptr<QtContainer>
3. QScopedPointer::data() Vs boost::scoped_ptr::get()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both do basically the same thing. The Qt version seems to have the ability to abscond with the pointer (`QScopedPointer::take()`), which allows you to transfer ownership to someone else. You can't do that with `scoped_ptr`, but you can swap both kinds.

`boost::scoped_ptr` and `QScopedPointer` are also is explicitly non-copyable.

`QScopedPointer` does have a mechanism that allows you to pass a "deleter" to the pointer. This is effectively a public static member of the given class, so `QScopedPointer` is still only the size of a pointer. It does mean that the type of `QScopedPointer` must include the deleter's type.

Both of them are made obsolete by `std::unqiue_ptr` in C++0x.

Comment: oh, so std::unqiue_ptr is preferred to any of the scoped pointers? and what about containers, do both behave the same way?

Comment: @blueskin: That's a separate question. So ask it separately.

Comment: QScopedPointer *is* non-copyable: [Q_DISABLE_COPY(QScopedPointer)](http://www.google.com/codesearch#79Flfm07AwU/trunk/qt.mod/src/corelib/tools/qscopedpointer.h&q=QScopedPointer&type=cs&l=87)

Comment: Wait, you are doing Qt? What's your opinion on Qt5's GL wrappers / enablers (if I may ask :))?